# Chrome Extension - Load popup whenever Facebook is visited?

Tags: google-chrome, popup, google-chrome-extension

I'm just starting on a Chrome extension. I want it to load a popup element whenever the browser loads a Facebook url.

**Is this possible? And how?** // ANSWERED.

---

Okay, then.

Now, I now how to make an extension that drops down in a small window at the top right of the page beneath the extension icons. **But how can I create a new div anywhere on the web page, like this buzzgrowl extension:http://buzzgrowl.com/ **?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yep it's possible. You can trigger a popup in your javascript. Set it to work only on facebook.com.

You can also do javascript checking of the url via window.location.